# How to find prime number's but theres bugs. I can't find out

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I write a program that find the prime numbers . My teacher told me to do that in three steps . Firstly i had to generate all odds numbers . Then i need to check if it is devigable or not . To do that he tell me to use % operator . Here is my code :

```
for num in range(3,10):
    if num%2 != 0: #generating odds
        for i in range(3,num):
            if num%i != 0:
                print num
            else:
                None
    else:
        None
```

Now my question is , the above code is right to generate prime ?

The above code gives me wrong ans . But where's the bugs here ? I need the explenation .

Sample output of the above code is:
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9
9
9
9
9
9

Comment: provide sample output

Comment: I edit the ques with sample out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `for` loop should be terminated if `num` is not a prime number.

```
for num in range(3, 100):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        for i in range(3, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

I found [the official document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for you:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Luckily, it provides with a sample about prime number.

Comment: The last else statement remains at the level of second for statement . I can't undestand that . Do it should at the level of second if statement ? If so , then the result is wrong . Can you please explain in brief about the use of else statement here

Comment: @user6359012 if the second `for` loop never trigger off `break`, then it goto execute statement in `else`

Comment: Thank you . I understand now .

Comment: For completeness sake, '2' should be included in the output.
Namely, the script should look like so: 
print(2),;for num in range(3, 100):;    if num % 2 != 0:;        for i in range(3, num):;            if num % i == 0:;                break;        else:;            print(num),;

Answer (score 1):

You have some correct ideas, but also some bugs. Since you mentioned a teacher I'll not give you a code example, just some hints.

You iterate (count upwards) for all numbers from 3 to 10. That's missing the number 2 already, which is also prime. You should just print that before everything else, to be complete.

Then you check if a number is odd by `%2`. That is a good idea, but it is also possible in python to iterate over only odd numbers by using `range(3,10,2)` instead. The last number is the step size, so it would count `3, 5, 7, 9`.
(This is just an enhancement, nothing wrong with your version)

Next you loop over all numbers smaller than the current number. First, you can already stop at `num/2`, because a divisor cannot be larger than that.
Your bug comes now: you print `num` every time one of the `i` does not divide. This is not a prime number. It's only a prime number if NONE of the numbers `i` divide `num`. I suggest you reverse your logic: print in the `else` statement and use the python statement `break` to escape the loop if one of the `i`s divide.

Additionally: `else: None` doesn't do anything, you can just leave it out. In Python not every `if` has to have an `else`.

Comment: Thanks . Its so helpful .

Answer (score -2):

i provide pseudo code in C language you understand it and try

```
int num=40; //your variable
for(int i=3;i<num;i++)
{
 if(i%2!=0)  //odd
 {
    int j=3;
    for( ;j<i;J++)
    {
     if(i%j==0)
      {
       printf("not Prime");
       break;
      }
    }
   if(i==j)
    {
     printf("num is prime=%d",&i);
    }

}
else
{
 printf("none")
}
}
```